# Why is the double-endorsement section on tzscan still empty?

Tags: baking, tzscan

As you can see on [tzscan's double-endorsement page](https://tzscan.io/double-endorsement), there are no evidence yet.

but, why ?

- never occurred till now (very unlikely)
- the accuser does not recognize them yet
- other reason

I'd be very curious to know, tnks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt to explain why it is not surprising that we would see many more double bakes than endorsements:

Under very nice conditions, with a deterministic signature scheme (like ed25519), you will not double endorse. Even if you fail to protect against double endorsements, if you sign endorsements *for the same block* twice, they are the very same endorsements, and there is no problem.

Conditions won't always be very nice! But they have often been pretty nice so far.

In contrast, one can easily double bake even under very nice conditions and with a deterministic signature scheme, by failing to protect against it. There is the proof of work nonce, the timestamp, the block contents... anything different will produce a different block, and so a double bake.

Answer (score 3):

I would say (99.99% sure) that double endorsement didn't happen until now. But, I may be wrong !